# phalcon row locking with models

Tags: database, innodb, phalcon, rowlocking

Since forUpdate still don't work (https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2407), what is best way to lock SELECTed rows in db?

I have a innodb table with items to process. I start via cronjob some tasks, which look after items to process `(status=open)`, update the row with `status=processing` and then do some stuff. How can i protect the time between

```
$oModel->findFirst('status="open"');
```

and

```
$oModel->update(['status' => 'processing']);
```

?

Comment: The issue says: Implemented in Phalcon 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting an options for_update => true.

```
$this->db->begin();

$oModel->findFirst( [
   'conditions' => 'status="open"',
   'for_update' => true
] );

$oModel->status = 'processing';

$oModel->update();

$this->db->commit();
```

the for_update option will set exclusive lock on each row it reads.
also can see document https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html